# Data duplicated in datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, duplicate-data

I have a problem with a dataTable component using Tomahawk.

I want to make a datatable with subcolumns in some columns. Something like that:

[image: My datatable]
This table only have 2 rows but its duplicated. Here is the code:

```
    <t:dataTable id="tabla1" value="#{userControl.mc64cljobs_encolados}" var="clh"> 
                        <t:column id="col1" >
                         <f:facet name="header" >
                              <h:outputText styleClass="leftColumn" value="Options"/>
                         </f:facet>
                         <t:dataTable id="tabla2" value="#{userControl.mc64cljobs_encolados}" var="clh1">
                             <t:column id="col11">
                                <f:facet name="header" >
                                    <h:outputText styleClass="leftColumn" value="Delete Work"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                    <center>
                                        <h:form>
                                            <h:commandLink actionListener="#{userControl.eliminaTrabajo(clh1.codigo, 'multicore64clustalwtrabajos', userControl.user, userControl.password, clh1.fileSequences, '')}"  value="Delete" />
                                        </h:form>
                                    </center>



</t:column>          

                        <t:column id="col12">
                            <f:facet name="header" >
                                 File Sequence Fasta
                            </f:facet>
                            <center>
                                <h:form>
                                   <h:commandLink target="popupWindow" action="popupWindow" actionListener="#{userControl.setOpenFile(clh1.fileSequences)}"  value="FILE 1" />
                                </h:form>
                            </center>
                        </t:column>
                 </t:dataTable>

        </t:column>





<t:column id="col2" >
                   <f:facet  name="header">
                        Pairwise alignment parameters
                   </f:facet> 

                 <t:dataTable id="tabla3" value="#{userControl.mc64cljobs_encolados}" var="clh2" >
                 <t:column id="col21" >
                     <f:facet name="header"  >
                        Gap Open Cost
                   </f:facet>  
                     #{clh2.costeOpenGap}

                </t:column>
                 <t:column  id="col22">
                   <f:facet  name="header">
                        Gap Extend Cost
                   </f:facet>  
                     #{clh2.costeExtendGap}

                </t:column>

                   <t:column  id="col23">
                     <f:facet name="header"  >
                        Cost Matrix
                   </f:facet>  
                     #{clh2.scoringMatrix}



  </t:column>
                 <t:column  id="col24">
                   <f:facet  name="header">
                        Cost Match/Replace
                   </f:facet>  
                     #{clh2.costeMatchReplace}

                </t:column>
                 </t:dataTable>
             </t:column>
          </h:dataTable>
```

What is my error in that code? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: no ideas? someone could post an example of a datatable with subcolumns please?

Comment: for start remove all those <h:form> tags from inside the table columns and make sure there is only one <h:form> that wrap your table

Answer (score 1):

Check this :
[Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)
The getter can be called more than one times in jsf lifecycle